# Laravel 5, Use URL for setting active class

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.3

Have stripped this right back but basically I have a very simple list, I want to add class 'active' to the list item if `Request::is('url')` returns true.

```
<ul>
    <li class="{{ Request::is('one') ? 'active' : '' }}">One</li>
    <li class="{{ Request::is('two/sub') ? 'active' : '' }}">Two</li>
</ul>
```

This works perfectly fine for most of my requests, however if my request looks something like the below..

```
http://homestead.app/one?search=some_search_string
```

.. li 'one' would still be active, I do not want this, If there are extra parameters I do not want the class active applied.

How would I go about putting this behaviour into place?

Comment: You mean to say extra parameters like `?search=search_string`?

Comment: Yeah, if there are any parameters i would like it to return false, meaning the list item is not active

Comment: For anyone visiting this question later, both answers worked perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it by `$_GET` try like this

```
  <li class="{{ (Request::is('one') && !count($_GET)) ? 'active' : '' }}">One</li>
```

Comment: Spot on, Thank you @Rishi

Answer (score 1):

Exactly @Rishi I agree with your solution.

```
<ul>
    <li class="{{ (Request::is('one') && !count($request->query)) ? 'active' : '' }}">One</li>
    <li class="{{ (Request::is('two/sub') !count($request->query)) ? 'active' : '' }}">Two</li>
</ul>
```